# My android application have connection issue with server when connected with wifi and work fine with mobile data

Tags: android, api, retrofit

I have a mobile application in which I am using retrofit API for get list of records i am facing some strange issue:

When I connect with office WIFI then its take more time for load data and some time show timeout while other application like YOUTUBE, FACEBOOK works fine same time but its too fast when connect with mobile data please help for sort out this problem thanks.

Comment: Maybe there is a firewall in your company's wifi.